# Why is there no change in "z" String array elements?

Tags: java, string, replace

I am practicing a program in which I am replacing all the 'S' with 'E' and vice-versa. There are several strings in which this task has to be done.

I have tried several things (like using replace()) but I cannot understand what's wrong.

```
int a;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
a = s.nextInt();
String[] x = new String[a];
String[] z = new String[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    x[i] = s.next();
}
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("S","A");
    z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("E","S");
    z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("A","E");
    System.out.println(z[i]);
}
```

For string SEES, the result displayed should be ESSE, but the answer is SEES.

Comment: Not Sure what you are trying to do but `z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("A","E")` is the last, beating all assingment.

Comment: Also note that it will only work correctly if there is no `A` in your string already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is:

1. Input "SEES"
2. Replace all "S" in "SEES" with "A" and get "AEEA"
3. Replace all "E" in "AEEA" with "S" and get "ASSA"
4. Replace all "A" in "ASSA" with "E" and get "ESSE"

But you are always operating on your *initial input* `x`, so what you are actually doing is:

1. Input "SEES"
2. Replace all "S" in "SEES" with "A" and get "AEEA"
3. Replace all "E" in "SEES" with "S" and get "SSSS"
4. Replace all "A" in "SEES" with "E" and get "SEES"

Here's your fixed code:

```
int a;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
a = s.nextInt();
String[] x = new String[a];
String[] z = new String[a];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    x[i] = s.next();
}
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("S","A");
    z[i]=z[i].replaceAll("E","S");
    z[i]=z[i].replaceAll("A","E");
    System.out.println(z[i]);
}
```

Note the two changes from `x[i].replaceAll` to `z[i].replaceAll`.

Comment: Instead of `'A'`, you may want to consider using a non-letter such as `'$'`, or even `'\0'` or `'\377'` as the temporary replacement for `'S'`, in order to avoid accidentally turning "real" `'A'`s into `'E'`s.

Answer (score 1):

With this line:

```
z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("S","A");
```

you store the changes in `z[i]`. Then with this line:

```
z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("E","S");
```

you overwrite the previous changes in `z[i]` with the new ones. 
And finally with this line:

```
z[i]=x[i].replaceAll("A","E");
```

you overwrite again the previous changes in `z[i]`. 
So if your original string is `SEES` then the last line will replace all `A`s to `E`s and since there is no `A` in `SEES` the string remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your program is that, your are not realizing that `x[i].replaceAll()` does not change the value of `x[i]`. Only the returned `String` has the replaced value.

You can do this with a single array like in below program.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringReplace {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] x = new String[4];
    x[0] = "S";
    x[1] = "E";
    x[2] = "E";
    x[3] = "S";

    System.out.println("Input:  " + Arrays.toString(x));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      x[i]=x[i].replaceAll("S","A");
      x[i]=x[i].replaceAll("E","S");
      x[i]=x[i].replaceAll("A","E");
    }
    System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.toString(x));
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Input:  [S, E, E, S]
Output: [E, S, S, E]
```